# How to save SKProduct object locally?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

I have tried to save a SKProduct object with archiving it with the class NSKeyedArchiver but it generates an error as **-[SKProduct encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**.

```
+ (void)saveProduct:(SKProduct *)product
{
     NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:product];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:data forKey:PRODUCT];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Is there a way to save an instance of SKProduct or not?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here. Why would you want to do this? I'd rather reload the product from the App Store when I need it, to ensure that the product is still offered and to check its price. Also, you don't know how store kit and `SKProduct` communicate with the App Store, and how `SKProduct` is wired with the rest of store kit.

Comment: Requesting data each time to retrieve all the product is a time consuming and for the introspection, one time is enough to ensure the price.

Comment: Well, even if you know the price, you will most likely not be able to go to the `SKPaymentQueue` with it because it won't be "wired up" with the rest of store kit properly. Also see the comment by @endy on this. If you are really eager to save time, you can load it somewhere in the background, but at least once per launch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SKProduct class needs to conform to the NSCoding protocol.

In other words you need to fill out these two methods in your SKProduct class.

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder;
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;

This will take your SKProduct class and break it down so that it can be serialized and unserialized.

Comment: So i need to create a category to add these two methods. Is there another way to save it rather than this?

Comment: I didn't realize SKProduct was a Apple class. In fact, there are probably alot of private properties to the SKProduct class and serializing them would probably fall under using a private API. not including the priviate properties would not yeild the results you want. I would suggest rethinking why you need to serialize these objects and look for an alternative.