# NSCoding error with SKProduct in Swift

Tags: swift, realm, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver, skproduct

I'm trying to save SKProduct in Realm but at begging I'm trying to convert SKProduct to NSData but I'm getting this error **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SKProduct encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14f5cd200'**
*

My class

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit

class ProductDataModel: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var product = SKProduct()

    // MARK: - var and let
    private let coderKey = "ProductDataModel"

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    convenience init(product: SKProduct) {
        self.init()
        self.product = product
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.product = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(coderKey) as! SKProduct

    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.product, forKey: coderKey)
    }
}
```

I try to archive it in another class

```
 let productData = ProductDataModel(product: product)
 let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(productData)
```

I did it in different ways but the result is the same. How can I fix it?

Comment: serializing SKProduct would probably fall under using a private API. I would suggest taking and storing only the required information from it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save SKProduct object locally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178790/how-to-save-skproduct-object-locally)

Comment: @sargeras No, It isn't. I read this questions and answer, but I cannot to make it in SKProduct extension in swift

Comment: SKProduct needs to conform to the NSCoding, you can do so by creating an extension, but I definitely feel it is not allowed....

Comment: @sargeras yes, I tried it

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you want to do this?

Comment: @OlivierWilkinson I get this task from my manager, I told him that it's incorrect task.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be saving SKProduct. If you decide to implement NSCoding methods you will need access to the property accessors which are considered private API. Using private API will likely result in AppStore rejection. If you only need the info from SKProduct you may want to create another class that implements NSCopying and save an instance of your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved it that we paste `SKProduct` array to the singleton and use it. I know that it's a bad solution but I don't know another.